# Why isn't my nested navigation bar dropping down properly?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a dropdown menu to my navigation bar but i am not being able to do it properly ? Can anyone help me to properly format it so that that would drop down properly whenever hovered ?

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Website</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
    background-color:   #311310;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%:
}
nav ul li ul li {
    background: #311310;
    display: block;
}
nav ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 100px;
}
nav ul li {
    color: #d9d9d9;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-family: klavika;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: #d9d9d9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

And here is the broken navigation bar Snap :

[image: Navigation Bar]

How can i display the *nested* one right below *about* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `position: relative;` to the parent:

```css
nav ul li {
    color:              #d9d9d9;
    display:            inline;
    padding:            0px 10px;
    font-family:        klavika;
    font-size:          14pt;
    position:           relative;
}
```

And `position: absolute;` to the menu:

```css
nav ul li ul {
    background: #311310;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: @mistgeek Can you make a jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: And my question is there is only one item in the dropdown list why is that so ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60527/discussion-between-mistgeek-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

add  `position: relative` for `nav ul li`